# Wrong path when executing npm command

Tags: angular, npm, command-line

I'm trying to execute npm command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I got the following exception

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any ideas why how can i change double slashes or why this issue occurs ?

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using? `node -v` `npm -v`

Comment: npm  6.4.1
node v8.12.0